# Must crossblooded sorcerer be crossblooded bloodrager if they multiclass?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, sorcerer, bloodrager

A crossblooded sorcerer multiclasses as a bloodrager. According to the rules for hybrid classes:

> Parent Classes: Each one of the following classes lists two classes that it draws upon to form the basis of its theme. While a character can multiclass with these parent classes, this usually results in redundant abilities. **Such abilities don't stack unless specified. If a class feature allows the character to make a one-time choice (such as a bloodline), that choice must match similar choices made by the parent classes and vice-versa (such as selecting the same bloodline).** The new classes presented here are all hybrids of two existing core or base classes.

Must the character take the crossblooded rager archetype of bloodrager in order to match the bloodlines, or must they select only one matching bloodline, or is something else true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, the crossblooded archetype does not have to be used for both classes**

A crossblooded sorcerer who takes a level in bloodrager must choose one of his existing bloodlines, but does not have to take the crossblooded archetype - there is no such restriction anywhere that I can find, and the freedom to have one crossblooded and one non-crossblooded class is seen in the bloodrager crossblooded archetype rules ([d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/archetypes/paizo---bloodrager-archetypes/crossblooded-rager)):

> If the crossblooded rager already has a bloodline from another class, one of the chosen bloodlines must be that bloodline.

There is even the chance that the GM may let you change one of your existing bloodlines to accommodate your new bloodrager preferences, although [this rule](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager#TOC-Bloodline) talks about a bloodrager that takes a level in a different class, not the other way around:

> If the bloodrager takes levels in another class that grants a bloodline, the bloodlines must be the same type, even if that means that the bloodline of one of the classes must change. Subject to GM discretion, the bloodrager can change his former bloodline to make them conform.